# Pygame, how to print content of a sprite group?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a sprite group called pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

How do I view the sprite that are inside this group ? (for debugging )

I want the name of every sprite that are indide this group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read PyGame doc - you have [sprites()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.sprites) methods which gives you list of all sprites in group.